# Instagram API: when is the rate limit increased for my client app?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I got an client app in sandbox for Instagram, was thinking of using it for showing a widget on client websites with their users recent media.

At the moment I am using GET requests towards this endpoint:
- **api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN**

This is done on the server side, and it works good with my sandbox user. I save the data response from the API to avoid reaching the rate limit of 500 each hour. The saved response is then formatted to a html list, with links to the media. The request is only done once each day at the moment.

Is the rate limit only incremented on API calls as I thought? Do I avoid hitting the rate limit with this solution? If not: when is the rate limit incremented exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rate limit will be decremented by 1 for your GET request. One way to keep track of the rate limit is to check the response headers from Instagram for `x-ratelimit-remaining`[1]. This will be set to an integer value (eg, 4990) and applies to the access_token used for the request. This method works only for GET requests; POST requests do not return accurate `x-ratelimit-remaining` values.

[1] As described in the [deprecated developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/deprecated/limits/) but inexplicably omitted from the [current documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/).

Comment: Thanks! Weird how they left out that important part in the new documentation, seems like useful information. Then I do not get to worry that I might hit the rate limit in my client applications.